# Reg File Import - Printer Mapping

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, registry

I am trying to split the entries in reg files, which are in the format:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices]
"Send To OneNote 2013"="winspool,nul:"
"Adobe PDF"="winspool,Ne02:"
"\\\\myprint\\ZX101_HP1201C2220C"="winspool,Ne03:"
"\\\\myprint\\HSJD201_LexMark1024iFF"="winspool,Ne04:"
```

I am only trying to output `ZX101`, `HSJD201`; which always comes before a "`_`" (see the last two lines). Other commonality here is the `\\\\myprint\\` always comes prior to these above mentioned entities that I am trying to capture.

Other entries in the reg file need to be ignored, like "OneNote, Adobe PDF".

I know that in the second line "`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`" will also be picked up because it contains "`_`"; but that is fine.

Edit 1 - Request for my code

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=myprint\\" %%a in ("C:\Users\admin\Printers_Mapped - Copy.txt") do set Value=%%a
```

Comment: If you show us your attempt by editing it into your question, we'll try fixing it, but as it stands your current post is a code request, which is not the purpose of SO

Comment: Apologies, my attempt updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,3delims=_\" %%a in ("%filename1%") do IF "%%a"=="myprint" echo Value=%%b
```

where `filename1` contains potatoes.

`delims` specifies a **set of** delimiter-characters, not a string.

`tokens=*` specifies the entire line is to be assigned, not individual tokens.

Using `\` and `_` as delimiters, the critical lines are tokenised as

1. "
2. myprint
3. *required data*

Comment: Thanks a lot @magoo, appreciate it. Just wanted to add one more thing, I later realised that outputs were not coming because I was trying to read a text file in Unicode format (when you export reg files to a txt file) and had to convert the files to ANSI.